# What is $\int_{|\vec x| = 1, z \geq 0}(x^2+y^2)^pz^q$ for $p,q \geq 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

What is $\int_{|\vec x = (x,y,z)| = 1, z \geq  0}(x^2+y^2)^pz^q$ for $p,q \geq 0$?
A hint is to use the Gamma function. I plugged in spherical coordinates and got:

$I = 2\pi \int \int r^{2p+q+2}sin^{2p+1}(\theta)cos^{q}(\theta)$. 
I don't see how to use the Gamma function here, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: $|x=(x,y,z)|=1 ??$

Comment: Note on this sphere, $x^2+y^2=1-z^2$. So the integral is the integral of $(1-z^2)^pz^q$.

Comment: Yeah, the double use of $x$ is confusing. @BehrouzMaleki I took it as $\vec x=(x,y,z)$ with the property $|\vec x|=1$.

Comment: so thanks...  :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I interpreted likewise.

Comment: I think this can be written as as $2\pi \int_{0}^{1} (1-z^2)^{p+1/2}z^q\,dz$. Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Substitute $z\to \sqrt{z}$ and recall the definition of the Beta function.  Then use its relationship to the Gamma function. -Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that on the sphere, $r=|\vec x|=1$.  Therefore, using spherical coordinates $(r=1,\theta,\phi)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \left(\sin(\theta)\right)^{2p+1}\left(\cos(\theta)\right)^q\,d\theta \,d\phi\\\\
&2\pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \left(\sin(\theta)\right)^{2p+1}\left(\cos(\theta)\right)^q\,d\theta\\\\
&=\pi B\left(p+1,\frac{q+1}{2}\right)\\\\
&=\pi \frac{\Gamma\left(p+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{q+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2p+q+3}{2}\right)} 
\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, using cylindrical coordinates $(\rho=\sqrt{1-z^2},\phi,z)$, we can write

$$I=2\pi \int_0^1 (1-z^2)^p z^q \,dz \tag 1$$

Enforcing the substitution $z\to \sqrt{z}$ into $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
I&=\pi \int_0^1 (1-z)^{p}z^{(q-1)/2}\,dz\\\\
&=\pi B\left(p+1,\frac{q+1}{2}\right)\\\\
&=\pi \frac{\Gamma\left(p+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{q+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2p+q+3}{2}\right)}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

---

And finally, using cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,\phi,z=\sqrt{1-\rho^2})$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
I&=2\pi \int_0^1 (\rho^2)^p (1-\rho^2)^{q/2} \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\,d\rho \\\\
&=2\pi\int_0^1 \rho^{2p+1}(1-\rho^2)^{(q-1)/2}\,d\rho\\\\
&=\pi\int_0^1 t^p(1-t)^{(q-1)/2}\,dt\\\\
&=\pi B\left(p+1,\frac{q+1}{2}\right)\\\\
&=\pi \frac{\Gamma\left(p+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{q+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2p+q+3}{2}\right)}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Thanks for this. One thing that I don't understand is: shouldn't it be B(2p+2,q+1)? Also, where did the $2\pi$ come from? Formally, what's the change of coordinates?

Comment: You're welcome.  I believe the result is correct.  The $2\pi$ results from integrating over $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.  The coordinate system chosen is spherical for which $z=\cos(\theta)$, $x^2+y^2=\sin^2(\theta)$, and $dS=\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi$ when $r=1$.

Comment: Alright, thanks for this!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: I best voted you - sorry I can't upvote you - I forgot this account's email password :(